ICS is not auto scheduling events in Google calendar
I don't know if i'm getting a problem with Google Calendar or its my ics file.
I have a API which generate a .ics file for one or multiple events.
When I'm testing sending vía email the .ics file attached with 5 o less events, Gmail works fine showing to me the div with the event and adding this to my calendar automaticaly.

but when i'm testing with a .ics file with 5 o more events, Gmail didn't do anything. I validated the .ics file in https://icalendar.org/validator.html and looks good.
So i dont know if i have a problem with my file or Google has a limit of events to auto schedule.
This is my .ics file with multiple events.
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
METHOD:REQUEST
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879574
SUMMARY:Clase 1
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240531T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 1 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879575
SUMMARY:Clase 2
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240607T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 2 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879576
SUMMARY:Clase 3
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240614T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 3 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879577
SUMMARY:Clase 4
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240621T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 4 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879578
SUMMARY:Clase 5
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240628T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 5 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879579
SUMMARY:Clase 6 Evaluación Oral 1
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240705T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 6 Evaluación Oral 1 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879580
SUMMARY:Clase 7
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240712T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 7 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879581
SUMMARY:Clase 8
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240719T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 8 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879582
SUMMARY:Clase 9
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240726T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 9 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879583
SUMMARY:Clase 10
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240802T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 10 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879584
SUMMARY:Clase 11
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240809T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 11 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:17205037/879585
SUMMARY:Clase 12 Evaluación Oral 2
DTSTAMP:20240603T174151Z
DTSTART:20240816T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:Clase Clase 12 Evaluación Oral 2 del curso Level 2 
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@email.cl
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE="INDIVIDUAL";X-NUM-GUESTS=0;ROLE="REQ-PARTICIPANT
    ";PARTSTAT="NEEDS-ACTION";CN="Attendee":mailto:attendee@email.cl
DURATION:PT90M
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR



I validated the .ics file in https://icalendar.org/validator.html and looks good.

I tried importing the .ics file manually as Google said here https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en&ref_topic=10510645&sjid=2799652173714157217-SA#zippy=%2Ccreate-or-edit-an-icalendar-file and works fine too.


